# How can we get a response send by a mobile application

Tags: php

I want to receive a code which is been send from the mobile application during confirmation process.And I should check through the database if the user is authorized.What should I do to receive and analyze the data?

Comment: I suggest you add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start by learning about RESTful API Design. RESTful principles provide strategies to handle CRUD actions using HTTP methods. REST for example would dictate the usage of PUT/PATCH to UPDATE a record in the database for whatever it may be (user/item/etc).

You could have a URI which handles the verification by checking the details the mobile application has sent to the server against the appropriate record in the database and then sending back an appropriate response.

Here's a good example of where you can get started; http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Comment: I believe that REST actually usually calls for `PUT` or `PATCH` as the HTTP verb for updating a record.